# jQuery for showing different text field showing when select two different items in selectbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to display the text fields when choosing different option from the selectoption (if select USA option USA text field need to show)?

```
<select name="cntry"> 
<option value="us">USA</option>
<option value="uk">uk</option>
</select >
<input type="text" value="USA" name="USA">
<input type="text" value="UK" name="UK">
```

Comment: Somehow you forgot to add the most important part: The code you're having issues with. Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#country').on('change', function() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });
  if (this.value === 'us') {
    $('input[name="USA"]').css('display', 'initial')
  }
  if (this.value === 'uk') {
    $('input[name="UK"]').css('display', 'initial')
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country" name="cntry">
  <option selected disabled hidden>Select your Country</option>
  <option value="us">USA</option>
  <option value="uk">uk</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="USA" name="USA">
<input type="text" value="UK" name="UK">
```